# Library Image with jsf does not appear

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

I put some images in my application but the images are not appearing,I'm using jsf

UPDATE

```
 <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="logo_pull_left">

                     <h:commandLink action="index.xhtml">
                   <h:graphicImage library="resources" name="winnerlogo.png"/> 
                     </h:commandLink>

              </h:panelGroup>
```

my page with the image that should appear

UPDATE
[image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pobwT.jpg)

Comment: try to use this "imagens/winnerlogo.png" instead of "winnerlogo.png"

Comment: Did not work bro

Comment: The folder `imagens` should be inside the `WEB-INF` folder

Comment: Did not work again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a direcory named `resources` and inside it a directory named `imagens`.
Then your code will work.

Comment: I created the resources directory and placed the images inside but it did not work

Comment: I put the update hirearquia  with directory resources  in the image 3

Comment: @FelipePatrocinio, your code should be `<h:graphicImage library="imagens" name="winnerlogo.png"/>`. Library is the directory named inside the `resources`directory.

Comment: Thanks, man, I got it right here and it worked thanks for the help.